# UISlider.value to UILabel.text SIGABRT ERROR

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uislider

I am trying to get the value of a UISlider to be displayed on a UILabel here is my code in the .m file:

```
- (IBAction)wordLengthChanged:(id)sender {

int sliderWordValue = _wordSlider.value;

NSString *wordValueChanging = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", sliderWordValue];

self.wordValue.text = wordValueChanging;
}


- (IBAction)livesChanged:(id)sender {

int sliderLivesValue = _livesSlider.value;

NSString *livesValueChanging = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", sliderLivesValue];

self.wordValue.text = livesValueChanging;
}
```

and here is my code in the .h file..

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *livesValue;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *livesSlider;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *wordValue;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *wordSlider;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)wordLengthChanged:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)livesChanged:(id)sender;
```

but the only problem is when I launch the app and I get the error Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What is the exception message and stack trace?

Comment: And almost equally importantly, what is the reason for tagging this with Xcode? (Actually, I know the reason very well...)